# Task.WaitAll / Task.WhenAll returning when not all tasks are disposable

Tags: c#, windows-services, task

We are developing a Windows Service, when this service gets stopped via taskmanager -> services -> stop service or via service snap in, my running "LoadBalancer" gets stopped via cancellation token, however when the using declaration triggers the disposing of my LoadBalancer it throws

> InvalidOperationException "A task may only be disposed if it is in a
>   completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled)."

We have tested the "Balancer" (not really a balancer sorry) up and down and there is no problem with it. The exception really only occurs when the windows service gets stopped. Could this be due to the way `Task.WaitAll`/`Task.WhenAll` is implemented? Maybe the `Task` that waits for the completion gets killed prior to the completion of my created tasks?

```cs
    void Main()
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
        int rangeCount = 10;
        int rangeIndex = 0;

        using (var balancer = new LoadBalancer<int>(cancellationToken: tokenSource.Token)
            .With(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(100).Wait();
                return Enumerable.Range(rangeIndex++ * rangeCount, rangeCount);
            })
            .With((i) => {

                if (i == 200) throw new Exception("stop me");
                i.Dump();
                Task.Delay(100).Wait();
                return LoadBalancerResult.Done;
            }))
        {       
            balancer.Run();
        } // <---- exception occurs here only when stopping the windows service!
    }

    // Define other methods and classes here

    internal enum LoadBalancerResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Instructs the <see cref="LoadBalancer{LoadType}"/> to remove this item as it is processed correctly.
        /// </summary>
        Done,
        /// <summary>
        /// Instructs the <see cref="LoadBalancer{LoadType}"/> to push the item back into queue. 
        /// </summary>
        PushBack,
    }

    internal class LoadBalancer<LoadType> : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Task[] _tasks;
        private readonly uint _maxParallel;
        private readonly CancellationToken? _cancellationToken;

        private Func<IEnumerable<LoadType>> _loadRequest;
        private Func<LoadType, LoadBalancerResult> _operation;

        public LoadBalancer(uint maxParallel = 6, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
        {
            if (maxParallel == 0) throw new ArgumentException("maxParallel needs to be larger than 0");
            _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
            _maxParallel = maxParallel;
            _tasks = new Task[maxParallel];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Each thread will call this load request to get work. Works with <see cref="Queue{T}"/>.
        /// You should keep in mind, the lower the count of <see cref="LoadType"/> items is the better the balancing gets.
        /// </summary>
        public LoadBalancer<LoadType> With(Func<IEnumerable<LoadType>> loadRequest)
        {
            _loadRequest = loadRequest;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The operation that is performed on a <see cref="LoadType"/> object.
        /// </summary>
        public LoadBalancer<LoadType> With(Func<LoadType, LoadBalancerResult> operation)
        {
            _operation = operation;
            return this;
        }

        private void RunOperation()
        {
            Queue<LoadType> load = new Queue<LoadType>(_loadRequest.Invoke());
            while (load.Any())
            {
                // check cancellation before operation
                if (_cancellationToken != null && _cancellationToken.Value.IsCancellationRequested) { "CANCELLATION REQUESTED - QUEUE".Dump(); break;}

                var item = load.Dequeue();
                var result = _operation.Invoke(item);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case LoadBalancerResult.PushBack:
                        load.Enqueue(item);
                        break;
                    case LoadBalancerResult.Done:
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                // check cancellation after operation, but enqueue.
                if (_cancellationToken != null && _cancellationToken.Value.IsCancellationRequested) { "CANCELLATION REQUESTED - LOAD".Dump(); break;}

                if (!load.Any())
                    load = new Queue<LoadType>(_loadRequest.Invoke());
            }
        }

        public void RunAsync()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _maxParallel; i++)
            {
                if (_cancellationToken != null)
                    _tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(RunOperation, _cancellationToken.Value);
                else
                    _tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(RunOperation);
            }
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            RunAsync();

            Task.WaitAll(_tasks);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                var task = _tasks[i];
                if (task != null)
                {
                    task.Dispose();
                }
                _tasks[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I change the Dispose function of the LoadBalancer to this:

```cs
        public void Dispose()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                var task = _tasks[i];

                // even tho the task should be awaited properly, the freaking Task.WaitAll / Task.WhenAll 
                // functions return when a task is not disposeable. 
                while (!HasStatus(task, TaskStatus.Canceled, TaskStatus.Faulted, TaskStatus.RanToCompletion))
                    Thread.Sleep(10);

                if (task != null)
                {
                    task.Dispose();
                }
                _tasks[i] = null;
            }
        }

        bool HasStatus(Task task, params TaskStatus[] status)
            => status.Contains(task.Status);
```

the exception is not thrown anymore. However I do not expect the need of doing this kind of stuff when I use a framework method that should already do something like this?

Comment: In `LoadBalancer.Dispose`, can you check that the task has actually completed before calling `task.Dispose();` ?

Comment: Yes, see my edits. However what is the reason for Task.WaitAll if it is not working as expected... I guess there is a bug in the Task.WaitAll / Task.WhenAll or I simply missunderstand it.

Comment: Why are you disposing the task objects?

Comment: Analysis has reported that we have better performance when we dispose the tasks instead of GC.

Comment: Did analysis **verify** that you **would get** better performance, or are they reading somewhere on the internet that disposing of tasks must be done in cases of extreme performance requirements? I ask because the code here looks like it allocates N tasks, that keeps running until you stop the service, and then you try to dispose those N tasks and that crashes. I seriously doubt you will get any more performance here by disposing those N tasks.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you were generating tasks so quickly, and of the right type (they need to have a WaitHandle allocated to them in order to *need* disposing), that you risk running out of WaitHandle objects before GC can clean up the objects, yes, I agree, this would be a case for disposing of tasks, but the code here doesn't seem to indicate that this is what you're doing.

Comment: My assumption that someone read something on the internet and misunderstood the relationship to your code is that since you're now struggling to implement disposing of the tasks in the right way, I assume "analysis" did not do that either, in which case someone is most likely guessing. If you have performance issues with your code, my advice would be to profile it to find your bottlenecks and start optimizing those. If that turns out to be something related to tasks not being disposed, then OK, but I doubt that's what you'll find.

Comment: It is a requirement by our architects. No offense but that is really not the question anyways. Task.WaitAll / Task.WhenAll should behave as described in the documentation. If this would be the case we would not write here. Actually you might be right i could stop disposing them besides that codereviews would not get accepted it does not clearify the problem that is occuring.

Comment: I have to agree with @LasseVågsætherKarlsen here. In addition In my opinion this is not something an architect should be giving requirements on, its implementation detail not architecture.

Comment: Have you checked what the status of the tasks that won't dispose actually is?

Comment: And here is an idea. Could it be that an exception is thrown in one of the tasks, which causes the stack to start unwinding, reaching the end of that using statement, which then tries to dispose of tasks that haven't completed? Try catching exceptions inside each task and logging that and see if you get an exception at some point.

Comment: The only exception I get from your code by the way is that "stop me" exception, this is .NET Core 3, however. Could there be something different to .NET Framework in this perhaps?

Comment: How exactly are you stopping the tasks in the windows service? Simply cancelling the CTS?

Comment: Yes. The code is for demo purpose only. Thats the tricky  thing, that only happens in a windows service, when you stop it.